# How to redirect traffic to website's landing page to LinkedIn profile page?

Tags: .htaccess, url, linkedin-api

When it comes to server directives manipulation, I'm a complete novice. 
That being said, I'm finding it difficult to redirect traffic from a website's landing page (e.g. http://picselbocs.com), which is basically empty, to a LinkedIn profile page (e.g. http://ro.linkedin.com/in/andreioniga), but without redirecting traffic to other pages of the same website (e.g. http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/) to the same profile page on LinkedIn, by using an .htaccess file?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file in your **picselbocs.com** domain's document root, add:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://ro.linkedin.com/in/andreioniga
```

Include a `301` if you want the redirect to be permanent:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://ro.linkedin.com/in/andreioniga
```

Alternatively, you can use mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$  http://ro.linkedin.com/in/andreioniga [L,R=301]
```

Remove the `,R=301` if you *don't* want permanent redirects.